# .properties or .env equivalent for APEX Classes

Tags: apex

I am creating a Apex class to report bugs to [Bugsnag](https://bugsnagerrorreportingapi.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/notify/send-error-reports). This integration requires an API key as described in the documentation.

In other environments, I usually store this kind of information outside the code (i.e. .env file), so that I can easily change it without updating the source code.

I was wondering what would be the equivalent of an **.env** file or a **.properties** file when writing Apex classes.

**SOLUTION**

I've created a new **Custom Setting Definition** (Hierarchy) called **BugsnagSettings__c** with a Custom Field **API_KEY__c**.

Here is how I consume it inside my APEX class:

```
BugsnagSettings__c bugsnagSettings = BugsnagSettings__c.getOrgDefaults();
String apiKey = bugsnagSettings.API_Key__c;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To store configuration settings, we would typically use a [Custom Setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm) or [Custom Metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Metadata_CustomMetadata.htm). Both can be accessed in Apex Code, and both can be modified using the user interface without modifying code. There's slightly different semantics for each, so you'll want to read the documentation.